# Accessing Gmail, Calendar and Contacts using Exchange ActiveSync

Tags: gmail, google-apps, exchange-server, activesync

This maybe very noob and unworthy of stackoverflow.com, but nonetheless here goes:

I'm trying to write a custom application that syncs my Google data (emails, calendar and contacts) to the desktop (I know that there are several tools that let you do that, but curiosity only killed the cat!!).

I know that `m.google.com` is the sync sever I need to use. I've gone through [MS-ASHTTP].pdf, and got all the protocol information down.

Now, using either the cURL command-line or a tool (in Windows) such as Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/), I'm unable to make valid ActiveSync requests to `m.google.com`. Moreover the URI `/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync` doesn't exist on `m.google.com`, and searching Google turned up nothing for me. Need help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting to Google using ActiveSync should work (I have an Android app - Corporate Addressbook that does that successfully)

Use the following URL

https://m.google.com/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync?User=xyz@gmail.com&DeviceId=1234512345&DeviceType=Android&Cmd=xxxxx

Edit the email address and the command you are sending. Also you will need to send the auth string in the header

I have a [blog post](http://vivekiyer.net/2010/12/06/an-activesync-primer-the-options-request/) that should help.

Comment: Thanks @Vivek... My mistake was that I was trying to communicate using protocol version 14.0 while m.google.com supports upto 12.0 only, and m.hotmail.com only 2.5. Thanks again... your blog post was helpful.